# mysql order by count performance

Tags: mysql, performance, count, sql-order-by

I'm finding the following a little perplexing... if I perform the below queries, when sorting by the indexed value 'keyword' it takes 0.0008 seconds, but when sorting by 'count' it takes over 3 seconds.

The following takes approx 0.0008 seconds:

```
SELECT keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT pmid) as count 
    FROM keywords 
    WHERE (collection_id = 13262022107433) 
    GROUP BY keyword 
    order by keyword desc limit 1;
```

This takes over 3 seconds:

```
SELECT keyword, COUNT(DISTINCT pmid) as count 
    FROM keywords 
    WHERE (collection_id = 13262022107433) 
    GROUP BY keyword 
    order by count desc limit 1;
```

Is there a way of speeding up a sort on a result set when sorting by count? Should it really take that much longer? Are there any alternatives? The engine is InnoDB.

Many thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to add an additional index to assist the in the counting phase.

```
ALTER TABLE keywords ADD INDEX ckp_index (collection_id,keyword,pmid);
```

If you already have a compound index with collection_id and keyword only, the Query Optimizer will still include a lookup for the pmid field from the table.

By adding this new index, this will remove any table scans and perform index scans only.

This will speed the count(distinct pmid) portion of the query.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Interestingly, this does make a difference. Query time now down to 0.2 seconds! However, what if I need to perform a similar query but across multiple tables? An index across different tables for every possible criteria? Hmm... I shall continue experimenting! Many thanks.

Comment: I was analysing a query that ran up to 300ms, it seems that count(*) or count(column) does make a difference, which I can understand, but not by that much. It was reduced to 130ms. Here's the kicker that I don't understand (or really have the time to look it up), if I wrap my entire query and use that as a subquery where I perform my order by count on, it reduces the time to 34ms... Perhaps when in 1 query it tries to order it as it goes, whereas in a subquery it looks for the occurences it needs order to sort it, there's a limit coming after it as well so that might benefit from it

Comment: Nice, it worked because of the above `covering index`. But how to solve for join with multiple tables? 
@RolandoMySQLDBA

Answer (score 3):

Not unexpected, not avoidable. When this query is ordered by `keyword`, MySQL can just look at what keyword comes last, pick out the rows with that keyword, and count them. When you order by `count`, though, it has to count the rows for every keyword to figure out which one is highest. That's a lot more work!